# Qt 5.2.1 for Android on Windows not building

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

I'm trying to build a HelloWord application for Android with Qt compiled for cpu armeabi-v7a.

On the first building attempt I get this error:

```
C:\Android\android-ndk\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include\bits\move.h:33: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
```

so I add in my pro file this:

```
#INCLUDEPATH +=C:/Android/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include \
```

On the second attempt I get this error:

```
C:\Android\android-ndk\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include\bits\stl_relops.h:67: error: 
expected '{' before '_GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY' namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
C:\Android\android-ndk\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include\bits\stl_relops.h:67: error:
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
```

And now I don't know how resolve this problem.

Someone can help me?

Thank you,
Mattia

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you compile Qt yourself? If not, you must ensure that you're using the same compiler for your application as was used to compile Qt.
2. You shouldn't need to add any extra includes to your Qt-based project. Those are handled by the build system (qmake and the mkspecs).

So far it looks as if you're running pre-built Qt, and the compiler you're using to build your own application doesn't match what Qt expects.

Comment: Hi @Kuba Ober, I'm running a pre-built Qt, downloaded from qt-project.org. Most of the compiler settings are pre-compiled, so I setup only some enviroment variables and Android Option in Qt Option window. The compiler used is MinGW 4.8.