# Qt Mobile Application Error _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY

Tags: android, qt

I'm currently trying to run an application in my android device but i keep  receiving this error :

```
C:\Users\Computer\Documents\android-ndk-r11c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\bits\stl_relops.h:67: error: expected '{' before '_GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY'
 namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)

C:\Users\Computer\Documents\android-ndk-r11c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\bits\stl_relops.h:67: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
                                  ^
```

I saw this post : [Qt 5.2.1 for Android on Windows not building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457838/qt-5-2-1-for-android-on-windows-not-building)

But I dont understand this point and I think is the solution : "Did you compile Qt yourself? If not, you must ensure that you're using the same compiler for your application as was used to compile Qt."

Or maybe is due to another problem

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the problem was due to the version of the Android NDK, it work with the Android NDK 12 Beta